# PHP Why is my code not entering the foreach loop on line 20? The file_get_contents() doesnt seem to be working

Tags: php, file-get-contents, domparser

This screenshot shows that the URL is getting stored in $url

[image]

This screenshots shows that after I add echo $html to the code, it says undefined variable $url and file_get_contents(): filename cannot be empty

[image: Image2]

Also, I have tried almost everything that's there on stackoverflow including file_get_html() and cURL. Nothing seems to work. Please tell me where I'm going wrong here.

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$base_url = "https://www.instagram.com/";
$html = "";
if ( isset($_POST['username']) ) {
    $url = $base_url.htmlspecialchars($_POST['username'])."/";//concatenate $base_url to username to generate full URL
}
$html = file_get_contents($url); //access the URL in $url
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html); //get HTML of the webpage given by file_get_contents
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
$arr = (array)$tags;
if (empty($arr)) {
    echo 'emptyarray';
}
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    echo $tag->getAttribute('src');
}
?>
```

Edit:

If 'http:// stackoverflow.com/questions' is used instead of 'https:// www.instagram.com/ its_kushal_here' file_get_contents() is working fine and not failing.

Comment: `if ( isset($_POST['username']) ) {
    $url = $base_url.htmlspecialchars($_POST['username'])."/";
}` This segment is  not successful means your post was not successful

Comment: 1 - Remove all testing code : 'echo $url...' There is a lot of testing code that makes it harder to see what is happening-----
2 - Include 'simple_dom_html' file ------
3 - Try include the code snippets with codepen (http://codepen.io/)----
4 - Consider using comments to show what you are trying to do

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI Even I thought so. But, the first screenshot will show you that the POST is successful.

Comment: @Cason Noted and acted upon. Thank you.
Let me know if you figure out whats wrong.

Comment: So its easy .. go to instagram.com/its_kushal_here/  view source code and find img tag... do you ???

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI yes.. img tag is there and can be viewed from the browser by visiting the url and clicking 'view source'.
I need to access it using my PHP script.

Comment: See Chapter Notes: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php. The error message says html does not contain anything, so file_get_contents failed.

Comment: i don't see any ... img tag

Comment: @radicarl I read the manual. file_get_contents has failed, yes. Unable to find out why though. Already read almost everything there is. On failure it should return FALSE. It is not.

Comment: did you check your php.ini settings? echo phpinfo(); allow_url_fopen must be 1

Comment: @radicarl both local value and master value for allow_url_fopen is 'On'
should i change it to '1'?

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI I am certain. img tag is present on https://www.instagram.com/its_kushal_here

Comment: If you look at the source code of the site, there are no img-tags. Save the page and look at it with a text editor. There will be no img-tags. The img-tags you see, are created with javascript.

Comment: @radicarl I get it now. Can you recommend a workaround or a solution for the problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: there is a js object in the source code: window._shared, this contains a "display_src" for every pic. i would use a regex to extract the images from the js string

Comment: @radicarl I will try doing that.
one thing though. I saved the webpage and then opened it using brackets text editor. it has img tags. how is this possible then?

Comment: then your browser did not saved the page it got from the server. it saved the page after running all the js on the page. Firefox offers both options (something like save whole page and save only html).

Answer (score -1):

When you refreshed the page did you make sure your post parameters carried through to the new request ?

The issue seems to be here

```
if ( isset($_POST['username']) ) {
    $url = $base_url.htmlspecialchars($_POST['username'])."/";
}
```

If `$_POST['username']` is not set then `$url` will not be defined. Also remove the `@` from `@$doc->loadHTML($html);` so you can see the error it outputs. That will help you workout what fails after that point.

Comment: Kirsty Wright. Yes I made sure that the POST parameters were set. I didn't refresh the page. Instead, I filled out the form on the previous page again so that all the POST params get their values.
AND this is what i get extra after removing the '@'.

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Empty string supplied as input in C:\xampp\htdocs\instaDP\php\process.php on line 12